# Mosaic() function changes scale in GEE and disable Map.onClick to show results in Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, scale, mosaic

I am trying to compute EVI and NDVI series for a period of three months for a random German forest area. The idea is to compute the VIs from all available sensors to get the best temporal resolution. So I can compute the values from Sentinel 2, Landsat 8 and MODIS sensors without much effort.

For example, here is how I calculate EVI for Sentinel 2:

```
// Calculate EVI and add it as an additional band in Sentinel Col
var addEVI = function(image){
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var EVIExpression = '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / ((NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE) + 1))';
  var EVI = image.expression({
      expression: EVIExpression, 
        map:{
            'NIR': image.select('B8'),
            'RED': image.select('B4'),
            'BLUE': image.select('B2')
        }}).rename("EVISen");
        
  return image.addBands(EVI).set('system:time_start', image.date().millis());
}
var SenEviNdvi = ndviSenAdd.map(addEVI);
```

In addition to it, I have added a function that allows users to click on the map and retrieve the historical values of the VIs from all 3 sensors in a ui.Chart by running the following code:

```
Map.onClick(clickChart);
var temp = LanEviNdvi.select('NDVILan', 'EVILan').merge(SenEviNdvi.select('NDVISen', 'EVISen'))
          .merge(ModisEviNdvi.select('NDVIModis', 'EVIModis'));

function clickChart(clickedValues){
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(clickedValues.lon, clickedValues.lat);
  print(eviChart(temp, point));
}
//print(eviChart(eviMODIS, ee.Geometry.Point(8.55, 48.35)));
function eviChart(what, where){
  return ui.Chart.image.series(what, where).setOptions({title:'Landsat, Sentinel 2 and MODIS NDVI and EVI indices',
      pointSize: 4,lineWidth: 1,interpolateNulls: true,
        series: {
    //0: {lineWidth: 3, color: 'E37D05', pointSize: 7},
    0: {color: '#F73659', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
    1: {color: '#E38F04', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
    2: {color: '#AA523E', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
    3: {color: '#0CF90F'},
    4: {color: '#6FB27A'},
    5: {color: '#0A630B'}
  }
  })
}
```

Everything was running fine, with only one remark: the Sentinel 2 values were doubled in the chart, likely because my aoi covered multiple tiles. So I decided to mosaic the Sentinel 2 images before adding it to the Map.onClick function by running the following code:

```
// Mosaic function
function mosaicByDate(imcol){
  // imcol: An image collection
  // returns: An image collection
  var imlist = imcol.toList(imcol.size())

  var unique_dates = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")
  }).distinct()

  var mosaic_imlist = unique_dates.map(function(d){
    d = ee.Date(d)

    var im = imcol
      .filterDate(d, d.advance(1, "day"))
      .mosaic()

    return im.set(
        "system:time_start", d.millis(), 
        "system:id", d.format("YYYY-MM-dd"))
  })

  return ee.ImageCollection(mosaic_imlist)
}
```

This function returns a nice Image Collection aggregated by date, so I don't have repetitive values per day anymore. The problem now is that my Map.onClick function will not work anymore, unless I remove the Sentinel stack from it, and I receive the following error message:

**Error in map(ID=1_2_0):
Image.reduceRegion: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.**

I understand that the mosaic() function aggregates data at a different projection (EPSG 4326) and a completely weird scale (111319.49079327357 m, or 1 degree) and that might be causing the problem. If I use the function reproject() I get some random outliers in the graph, so I think it is not an option.

I am almost giving up on this. My only hope is that there is a way to force the mosaic() function to run at a specific given scale? Or any other way?

I would really appreciate any light! Cheers

Comment: Can you share the complete minimal code to reproduce the error? It might be that you are simply missing the `scale` parameter (in meters) in the call to `ui.Chart.image.series` and otherwise don't need to do an explicit reprojection.

Comment: The code is here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0aba467296a6228ce8b9b3ca53c8a43c
By now I have used reproject at line 322, which seems to work. But I heard I should be careful using reproject function.